# Bareos:One pool with different media types

Tags: bareos

In my bareos setup, I have 3+ virtual devices per client. These 3+ virtual devices per client have one media type that points to one physical location (directory). Every client has at least 4 pools; 2 pools use one virtual device (Incremental, Differential), and 2 pools use these two devices (1 pool/one device(virtual)).

In this setup, I have one media type for these 3+ virtual devices and these 4+ pools. Each of these 3+ virtual devices points to one directory per client. These 4+ pools per client have assigned these 3+ devices. So if I keep one media type per physical location (directory), I have no problem with restoring using any of these 3+ devices.

But now I discovered that these 4+ pools per client make things more complicated. I would like to reduce the above pools setup to around 13 pools. But this reducing requires keeping many different media types in one pool. I found information in the bareos manual that it could make problems e.g. with migration. Here is some information about that from the manual:

> Each Pool into which you migrate Jobs or Volumes must contain Volumes
>   of only one Media Type Dir Storage .
>
> Bareos permits Pools to contain Volumes of different Media Types.
>   However, when doing migration, this is a very undesirable condition.
>   For migration to work properly, you should use Pools containing only
>   Volumes of the same Media Type for all migration jobs.
>
> Above, we discussed how you could have a single device named
>   FileBackupSd Device that writes to volumes in
>   /var/lib/bareos/storage/. You can, in fact, run multiple concurrent
>   jobs using the Storage definition given with this example, and all the
>   jobs will simultaneously write into the Volume that is being written.
>   Now suppose you want to use multiple Pools, which means multiple
>   Volumes, or suppose you want each client to have its own Volume and
>   perhaps its own directory such as /home/bareos/client1 and /home-
>   /bareos/client2 ... . With the single Storage and Device definition
>   above, neither of these two is possible. Why? Because Bareos disk
>   storage follows the same rules as tape devices. Only one Volume can be
>   mounted on any Device at any time. If you want to simultaneously write
>   multiple Volumes, you will need multiple Device resources in your
>   Bareos Storage Daemon configuration and thus multiple Storage
>   resources in your Bareos Director configuration. Okay, so now you
>   should understand that you need multiple Device definitions in the
>   case of different directories or different Pools, but you also need to
>   know that the catalog data that Bareos keeps contains only the Media
>   Type and not the specific storage device. This permits a tape for
>   example to be re-read on any compatible tape drive. The compatibility
>   being determined by the Media Type (Media Type Dir Storage and Media
>   Type SdDevice ). The same applies to disk storage. Since a volume that
>   is written by a Device in say directory /home/bareos/backups cannot be
>   read by a Device with an Archive Device Sd Device =
>   /home/bareos/client1, you will not be able to restore all your files
>   if you give both those devices Media Type Sd Device = File. During the
>   restore, Bareos will simply choose the first available device, which
>   may not be the correct one. If this is confusing, just remember that
>   the Directory has only the Media Type and the Volume name. It does not
>   know the Archive Device Sd Device (or the full path) that is specified
>   in the Bareos Storage Daemon. Thus you must explicitly tie your
>   Volumes to the correct Device by using the Media Type.

Could you explain why I can't keep many different media types in one pool, if media type point to the right virtual device (directory)?

Why might it be a problem with migration in my case, when media type points to the right directory and volume?